# Best way to ask a user before submitting information to database

Tags: asp.net

I am having New Customer page wherein the user fills information abourt customers , what I was  planning to do is I wanted to display a popup where the user is asked whether he really wants to submit the information ,if he clicks yes then the information processing is continued and if he cancels then the submission wont continue.The popup I am talking wont be a javascript confirm.So how do I go about this , should I use `ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement` to show my popup , or is there any other alternative ,any suggestions are welcome , thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it would be better to use javascript here.  If you aren't happy with the way Javascript Confirm is displaying (i.e. you want it to look better) then you can use a Jquery UI Dialog Box.

You can visit http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation to see a demo of this and if you are happy with it you can use it in your code.  You can load the jquery js and jquery ui css from Google's CDN so that it loads faster for your users. (website is https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)

Comment: even I am planning to use javascript , but the difference is I am creating my own popup , rest is same

Comment: Don't know why you want to do that. If its for the looks then you can use a JQuery dialog box and customise the size, looks etc in your JSON object that you pass to the dialog and in your CSS.